# “The package could not be installed” when updating plugins, themes, and core files on WampServer

Tags: wordpress, wamp, wampserver

Whenever I update anything on my local WordPress development site, whether it be plugins, themes, or the WP 3.7.1 update, I get this error message:

> Unpacking the update…
>
> The package could not be installed.: PCLZIP_ERR_BAD_FORMAT (-10) :
>   Unable to find End of Central Dir Record signature
>
> Installation Failed

I'm using WampServer 2.4, with Apache 2.0.63, PHP 5.2.11, and MySQL 5.0.88.

Answer (score 1):

Check that you have activated your php_zip extension

Using a left click on the wampmanager icon, follow the menus as so:

```
wampmanager -> PHP -> PHP Extensions -> php_zip
```

If `php_zip` in the menu is not TICKED, click it, and wait for a few seconds while wampmanager restarts Apache.

Then check it has become ticked, if not, Exit wampmanager and restart it.

Then try installing again.